# Convert PDF to JPG or PNG using C# or Command Line

Tags: c#, pdf

I need to convert a PDF file to images. I used for testing purposes "Total PDF Converter" which offers a command line, but it's shareware and I need to find a free alternative.

Does anyone knows such a tool or maybe even a free C# library?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `convert` tool (or `magick` [since version 7](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli)) from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) bundle can do this (and a whole lot more).

In its simplest form, it's just

```
convert myfile.pdf myfile.png
```

or

```
magick myfile.pdf myfile.png
```

Comment: To expand on this answer, you would use the http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ProcessStart.aspx

Comment: I have tried ImageMagick and it works very well in image conversion. To work with pdf you will need to install GhostScript also. http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/

Comment: I tried this but for some reason I only get a white page with a black line in the middle and some random text on the side..

Comment: (it's a pdf with more than 1 page)

Comment: and I'm also a bit confused because of the licensing system here. ImageMagick is licensed under the Apache license which is fine but ghostscript is GPL. What does this mean for me when my program is shipped with a commercial program?

Comment: @Martin It probably means that you need to purchase a [commercial license from Artifex](http://www.artifex.com/indexlicense.htm) or use something else

Comment: When running in windows, the `convert` now names `magick` !!!

Comment: @Turtle: That's actually on all platforms since the recently released version 7, although on *nix you'd probably get symlinks. Edited it in.

Comment: `magick: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `gs' @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/384.`

Comment: @xeruf Sounds like a topic for a new question if you get stuck on that.

Answer (score 18):

As a GhostScript answer is missing and there is no hint for **multipage** PDF export yet I think adding another variant is ok.

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pnggray -r300 -dUseCropBox -sOutputFile=item-%03d.png examples.pdf
```

**Options description**:

- `dBatch` and `dNOPAUSE` just tell gs to run in batch mode, which means
  more or less it will not ask any questions. Those parameters are also
  important if you want to run the command in a bash script.
- `sDEVICE` tells gs what output format to produce. `pnggray` is for
  grayscale, `png16m` for 24-bit RGB color. If you insist on creating
  Jpegs use `-sDEVICE=jpeg` to produce color JPEG files. Use the `-dJPEGQ=N` (N is an integer from 0 to 100, default 75)
  parameter to control the Jpgeg quality.
- `-r300` sets the scan resolution to 300dpi. If you prefer a smaller
  output sizes use `-r70` or if you input pdf has a high resoultion use
  `-r600`. If you have a PDF with 300dpi and specify -r600 your images will be upscaled.
- `-dUseCropBox` tell gs to use a CropBox if defined. A CropBox is
  specifies an area of interest on a page. If you have a pdf with a
  large white margin and you don't want this margin on your output this
  option *might* help.
- `-sOutputFile` defines the name(s) of the output file. The %03d.png part
  tells gs to include a counter for multiple files. A two page pdf
  would result in two files named item-001.png and item-002.png.
- The last (unnamed parameter is the input file.)

**Availability:**
The convert command of imagemagick does use the gs command internally. If you can convert a pdf with imagemagick, you already have gs installed.

**Install ghostscript:**

RHEL:

```
yum install ghostscript
```

SLES:

```
zypper install ghostscript
```

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ghostscript
```

Windows:

You can find Windows binaries under http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

Answer (score 7):

The @Thomas answer didn't work in my case.
I gues that works only if you have images in your pdf.
In my case what worked was `pdftoppm` (source from https://askubuntu.com/a/50180/37527):

```
pdftoppm input.pdf outputname -png
```

This will output each page in the PDF using the format `outputname-01.png`, with `01` being the index of the page.

#### Converting a single page of the PDF

```
pdftoppm input.pdf outputname -png -f {page} -singlefile
```

Change `{page}` to the page number. It's indexed at 1, so `-f 1` would be the first page.

#### Specifying the converted image's resolution

The default resolution for this command is 150 DPI. Increasing it will result in both a larger file size and more detail.

To increase the resolution of the converted PDF, add the options `-rx {resolution}` and `-ry {resolution}`. For example:

```
pdftoppm input.pdf outputname -png -rx 300 -ry 300
```

Answer (score 6):

I have found this solution which worked for me:  https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET. It is also available as an nuget download.

Here is the sample code for converting all pdf pages into png images:

```
    private static void Test()
    {
        var localGhostscriptDll = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "gsdll64.dll");
        var localDllInfo = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(localGhostscriptDll);

        int desired_x_dpi = 96;
        int desired_y_dpi = 96;

        string inputPdfPath = "test.pdf";

        string outputPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

        GhostscriptRasterizer _rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer();

        _rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath, localDllInfo, false);

        for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= _rasterizer.PageCount; pageNumber++)
        {
            string pageFilePath = Path.Combine(outputPath, "Page-" + pageNumber.ToString() + ".png");

            Image img = _rasterizer.GetPage(desired_x_dpi, desired_y_dpi, pageNumber);
            img.Save(pageFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        _rasterizer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Warning: Don't forget to call the _rasterizer.Close() at the end. (It's important and avoid having exception in case you would use this code in a loop for example).

Comment: is there an alternative to 'GetPage' that will get the entire document that you know of?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this free solution

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API

It easily convert PDF to images (single file or multiple files)
is open source, and use ghostscript (free download)

Example of its use:

```
converter = new PDFConverter();
converter.JPEGQuality = 90;
converter.OutputFormat = "jpg";
string output = "output.jpg";
converter.Convert("input.pdf", output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use iText sharp. Its a port of an open source java project for manipulating PDFs. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: I cant use this because of the GPL license...

Answer (score 0):

[2JPEG](http://www.2jpeg.com/overview/pdf-to-jpg-converter) command line tool can do it, like:

```
2jpeg.exe -src "C:\In\\*.pdf" -dst "C:\Out"
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work with a lot of errors.

Comment: Hi Turtle,
Could you please tell me more info about 2JPEG errors you have?