# SSRS .net PDF to Image from SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, pdf, reporting-services

I have looked and there doesnt seem to be anything around to do this.

I have a database with a varbinary column that contains a PDF.
I want to display this as an image in SSRS.
I can't find any way with ghostscript or spire.pdf etc (the free options) that allow you to pass a stream as the pdf input, and then output the images, they all seem to need an actual file.
Googling this gives a codeproject example from 2009 which uses a component you now have to buy, plus sqlclr which seems overly complicated.
I just want a .net class i can build and reference in my SSRS rdl file which i can pass the field as the result of the sql query and get back a list of images (1 per page)

Comment: If you are able to write a PDF to Image converter in C#, you could look into doing this with a custom code function in SSRS.

Comment: yes thats exactly what im trying to do, but cant find anything that will take the varbinary (byte array) as its input and return a list of images

Comment: There is nothing built into SSRS to do this.   You will have to write it.  If you are asking for third party app recommendations, that would be off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to display PDF stored in `VARBINARY(MAX)` directly in `SSRS`, I would try to obtain the images before generating the report:

1) use a tool to generate an image from a PDF (e.g. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)). More details about this conversion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695695/convert-pdf-to-jpg-or-png-using-c-sharp-or-command-line).

2) Display images in `SSRS` from `VARBINARY(MAX)` using [this tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2978/rendering-images-from-a-database-on-ssrs-reports/).

This means to have some redundancy (extra space needed), but reports will generate faster.